# Customize using ng-class angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have two css classes`.caret .right` and `.caret .down` this is my code

```
<span> ng-class="{'caret right': checkboxer[mainParent]==true,'caret down': checkboxer[mainParent]==false}" </span>
```

and my css

```
.caret .right{transform: rotate(270deg);}.caret .down{transform:rotate(360deg);}
```

the caret class is from bootstrap.
Its not affecting my span ? What error i have done?

Comment: `caret ` can be applied on traditional class attr. and about the code. can you provide a plunk?

Comment: try this `class="caret {{checkboxer[mainParent] ? 'right' : 'down'}}"`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/20GTiq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working plunk.

```
  <div ng-click="toggle()">
    <span ng-class="{'right-caret':checkbox,'caret': !checkbox}"></span> Caret
  </div>
```

Another simpler Approch

```
class="caret {{checkboxer[mainParent] ? 'right' : 'down'}}"
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbwproft/)

Comment: this is my css `.caret .right{
transform: rotate(270deg);

}
.caret .down{
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
`

Comment: Its working fine here. https://plnkr.co/edit/UTeq3yoNcdUP5Ojatkbr?p=preview

Comment: well I think you dont need additional css I guess because bootstrap is there . :)

Comment: when i click on caret it should change to down or right based on above written css,does the caret change direction for you?

Comment: oh so you want to customize the caret. ok wait I make another version of the caret for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125778/discussion-between-massdev-and-junaid-salaat).

Comment: @masSdev sorry for the late response but I've updated my answer for your requirement too and for other future users thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `checkboxer[mainParent]` returns a boolean then this is the solution.

```
<span class="caret" ng-class="{
        'right': checkboxer[mainParent],
        'down': !checkboxer[mainParent]
    }">

</span>
```

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/20GTiq?p=preview i have to customize caret is that possible?